# Why does equal remain unevaluated in this case?

Tags: evaluation, hold

This is not really an issue but rather a curiosity. Why does

`-1 + 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5 - 20/9 (-43 + Sqrt[1885])]) +  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5 - 20/9 (-43 + Sqrt[1885])]) == -1`

not evaluate to `True` but rather returns the input? There should be no issue here.

Note:

`Simplify[-1 + 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5 - 20/9 (-43 + Sqrt[1885])]) +  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5 - 20/9 (-43 + Sqrt[1885])]) == -1]`

Does return `True`

Comment: It would be really a bad idea if CAS did automatic simplification. It should be by user request. So it you type `Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x]^2` you do not want CAS to replace this `1` on its own.  But only if you wanted it to be `1` then you can use `Simplify`.  So this is a design issue.  And the right one.

Comment: I am not asking it for simplification, I am asking whether the two quantities are equal. Which is a True/False question. But I do understand your comment.

Comment: Without simplification Mathematica does not know they are identical. That is the point. How would it know?  Only when you call `Simplify` it will then find they are the same. Same for `Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1`. These are not identical, unless you ask to simplify the LHS.

Comment: `Equal` is intended to be fast (and usually is). A consequence is that it can return unevaluated even in cases where equality is in principle decidable.

Comment: From the docs for `Equal`, "lhs == rhs returns True if lhs and rhs are identical." The sides are not identical until `Simplify` or  something similar is used.

Comment: @BobHanlon ``5+5==10`` returns true.

Comment: Yes, because `5+5` automatically reduces to `10` and the `lhs` is identical to the `rhs`. Mathematica will automatically do some trivial simplifications, e.g., `x/x` is always `1` (and not conditionally 1).

Comment: I don't know that you can predict the exact boundaries of what will be evaluated: NO:`1/Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[2]] == Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[2]]`. But YES: `-1/Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[2]] == Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[2]]` and YES: `1/(-1 + Sqrt[2]) == 1 + Sqrt[2]`.